# Apache Velocity "main template"?

Tags: velocity, template-engine

I'm very new to Apache Velocity, and I'm having a little trouble figuring out the optimal way to structure my templates. In most of the guides I have seen the pages have been built like this:

```
#parse("header.vm")
<body>
    ...
</body>
#parse("footer.vm")
```

I have also seen someone come close to a "main" template with this approach:

```
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
#if($activeTab=="home")
    #parse("home.vm")
#elseif($activeTab=="aboutus")
    #parse("aboutus.vm")
...and so on.
</body>
```

Which seems a little silly, but I guess it works.

I've used Twirl a lot, so I might be spoiled, but I'd like to inject a template into another, essentially ending up with a main template like this:

```
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    $content
</body>
```

And then writing every other template as:

```
#parse(main){ 
    TEMPLATE CONTENT 
}
```

Is this possible in Velocity? If yes, is it bad practice, and if so why? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `$!bodyContent` variable.

mainLayout.vm:

```
#macro(mainLayout)
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    $!bodyContent
</body>
#end
```

index.vm:

```
#@mainLayout()
  <h1>Index page</h1>
#end
```

Answer (score 5):

Velocity itself doesn't provide good support to layout template (the main template as you called). However they provide a tool called [Velocity Layout Servlet](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/2.0/view-layoutservlet.html) (VLS).

To give you a heads up, some other templating solution like Rythm provides very nice template layout management via the [template inheritance mechanism](http://rythmengine.org/doc/template_guide.md#inheritance) ([demo](http://fiddle.rythmengine.org/#/editor/886606b3a7034088b991855bef8f89da)). Disclaimer: I am the author of Rythm so I might have some bias here. However you can checkout [this article](http://www.todaysoftmag.com/article/en/23/Template_Engines_for_Java_Web_Development_907) created by a third party to understand the pros and cons of different template solutions.

Comment: I found this github repo [spring-rythm](https://github.com/greenlaw110/spring-rythm). Is this yours? In what state would you say the projects is?

Comment: yes it's my repository. Although it's not widely used, I do use it in a couple of banking projects.